# Some Folder path to Tree structure

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

There is some path, it is list structure, like:

```
a=["/desktop/folderA/fileA","/desktop/folderA/folderX/file1","/diskKH/folderA/fileA","/desktop/folderB/folderC/fileX"]
```

It can be:

```
[{
    'name': 'diskC',
    'children': [{
        'name': 'folderA',
        'children': [{
            'name': 'test_file'
        }, {
            'name': 'sub_folderX',
            'children': {
                'name': 'file1'
            }
        }]
    }, {
        'name': 'folderB',
        'children': {
            'name': 'folderC',
            'children': {
                'name': 'fileX'
            }
        }
    }]
}, {
    'name': 'diskKH',
    'children': {
        'name': 'folderA',
        'children': {
            'name': 'test_file'
        }
    }
}]
```

I use this way:

```
import copy
def ChageArraryInverted(arrary):
    dict_1={}
    for index in range(len(arrary)-1,-1,-1):
        dict_1["name"]= arrary[index]
        dict_2=copy.copy(dict_1)
        dict_1["children"]=dict_2
    return dict_1["children"]

def GetResArrary(arrary):
    list_all=[]
    for item in arrary:
        item=str(item).split("/")[1::]
        item=ChageArraryInverted(item)
        list_all.append(item)
    print(list_all)
    return list_all



import pysnooper
# @pysnooper.snoop()

def Merge(dict1, dict2):
    result = copy.copy(dict1)
    if isinstance(dict1,dict):
        if dict1["name"] == dict2["name"]:
            if 'children' in dict1 and 'children' in dict2:
                if isinstance(dict1["children"], dict):
                    if dict1['children']['name'] == dict2['children']['name']:
                        result['children'] = [Merge(dict1['children'], dict2['children'])]
                    else:
                        result['children'] = [dict1['children'], dict2['children']]
                if isinstance(dict1["children"], list):
                    for index in range(0, len(dict1["children"])):
                        if dict1['children'][index]['name'] == dict2['children']['name']:
                            result['children'] = [Merge(dict1['children'][index], dict2['children'])]
                        else:
                            if dict2['children'] not in result['children']:
                                result['children'].append(dict2['children'])
            elif 'children' in dict1:
                result['children'] = [dict1['children']]
            elif 'children' in dict2:
                result['children'] = [dict2['chidlren']]
            else:
                if "children" in result:
                    del result['children']
            return result
        else:
            result = [result, dict2]
            return result
    elif isinstance(dict1,list):
        for index in range(0,len(dict1)):
            if dict1[index]["name"] == dict2["name"]:
                if 'children' in dict1[index] and 'children' in dict2:
                    if isinstance(dict1[index]["children"], dict):
                        if dict1[index]['children']['name'] == dict2['children']['name']:
                            result['children'] = [Merge(dict1[index]['children'], dict2['children'])]
                        else:
                            result['children'] = [dict1[index]['children'], dict2['children']]
                    if isinstance(dict1[index]["children"], list):
                        for index in range(0, len(dict1[index]["children"])):
                            if dict1[index]['children'][index]['name'] == dict2['children']['name']:
                                result['children'] = [Merge(dict1[index]['children'][index], dict2['children'])]
                            else:
                                if dict2['children'] not in result[index]['children']:
                                    result[index]['children'].append(dict2['children'])
                elif 'children' in dict1[index]:
                    result[index]['children'] = [dict1[index]['children']]
                elif 'children' in dict2:
                    result[index]['children'] = [dict2['chidlren']]
                else:
                    if "children" in result[index]:
                        del result[index]['children']
                return result
            else:
                result = [result, dict2]
                return result

def CirArraryToResult(list):
    re={}
    for index in range(0,len(list)):
        if index<len(list)-1:
            if len(re)==0:
                re=Merge(list[index],list[index+1])
            else:
                if(index==len(list)-1):
                    return re
                re=Merge(re,list[index+1])
    return re
a=["/desktop/folderA/fileA","/desktop/folderA/folderX/file1","/diskKH/folderA/fileA","/desktop/folderB/folderC/fileX"]
res=GetResArrary(a)
res=CirArraryToResult(res)
print("res:",res)
```

But I think there are more efficient algorithms, what can I do to improve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: oo,sorry ,I don't know this,i am a beginner.thinks